# What does "past" mean here?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

In the following passage

> If the suffering existed alone, it would be impossible to bear it. And if there were only bliss, that, too, would be ***past bearing***.

I wonder what ***past*** means here, none of the entries I find in several dictionaries seem to fit here. Is it used as a preposition? If yes, the two meanings I found on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk01C3f5FEHGd-jTnUCNy2Hak3j2znA%3A1608547180252&ei=bHvgX6zqDtOs1fAPo8ab-A4&q=past%20meaning&oq=past%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzINCAAQsQMQyQMQRhD5ATICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoECAAQRzoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECCMQJzoFCAAQkQI6BAgAEEM6CAguELEDEIMBOggIABCxAxCDAToFCAAQsQM6CAgAEMkDEJECOgUILhCRAjoECC4QQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoCCC46BAgAEAo6DQgAEMkDEJECEEYQ-QFQtdUGWJ-YB2DhnAdoAXADeACAAb8BiAHeDJIBBDAuMTKYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEKyAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis0KGa8d7tAhVTVhUIHSPjBu8Q4dUDCA0&uact=5) are

> 1. to or on the further side of.
> 2. beyond in time; later than.

I also met the expression "past understanding".

I was confused by this connotation, how can something be "***beyond (in time)*** bearing/understanding"?

Comment: How does the definition "beyond" not fit these examples?

Comment: it says beyond _**in time**_.  I was confused by this connotation, how can something be "byond (in time) bearing/understanding"? But I guess I shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*past* as used here is a preposition. And like prepositions do, it shows in what relation the first noun *bliss* (or equivalently, the pronoun *that*) stands in relation to the second one (the gerund *bearing* here).

*past* in this sense is defined as—

> Beyond the power, scope, extent, or influence of

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: Yes, that looks more like it. Thank you for pointing out this dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

I believe "past bearing" here means - "beyond bearable".

The first definition is a better fit here, though it makes sense when you take the whole phrase into consideration.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with time here.

Comment: @fev It's used in Sense 1, here—"on the further side of", as in "It's half _past_ nine."